# x86 Hardware/Software TSS usage

Tags: x86, operating-system, kernel, osdev, context-switch

I have a simple working (32-bit protected mode) kernel with clock interrupt. I can see that this interrupt is working because it prints « clock » a lot of time. I can also see that this interrupt gives back control to kernel because it prints « Kernel has stopped » on screen after few clock interrupts, like it is supposed to. Interrupts are located in same code segment as the kernel.

I did not set any TSS, but it is working. I can read on this article (https://web.archive.org/web/20160326062442/http://jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/10.-User%20Mode.html) that when an interrupt occurs, the cpu will look into the selected TSS segment to update the registers.

1. How can it work if I don’t have this TSS ? Is it because when interrupts occurs the CPU will still automatically push EIP, CS, EFLAGS, EPS, SS and restore them on iret ?
2. If I load a single TSS, how this interrupt will know that it should use this TSS ? With ltr instruction that will take the according tss segment inside the GDT?
3. Not really related, but when using hardware context switching and jmp to one TSS, will it automatically jump to the previous (no next field so I’m a little bit lost) tss segment automatically when return ?

These are questions I cannot really have a clear answer for from my school courses neither osdev, or this forum.

Comment: If you are running everything in Ring 0 then you don't need a TSS as there are no ring transitions that will occur. If however you have code running in Ring 3 (What most people call user mode), you will need a TSS to transition from Ring 3 to Ring 0 on an interrupt. When everything is in Ring 0 when an interrupt occurs the kernel (Ring 0) stack will be used to push interrupt data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Michael Petch explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946642/x86-hardware-software-tss-usage#comment121849172_68946642) in the comments, you don't need a TSS if the interrupt handler is executing at the same privilege.

The CPU will read the necessary `SS:SP` pair from the TSS only if the interrupt is going to be executed in a more privileged ring w.r.t the current code's ring (e.g. a transition from ring 3 to ring 0).
This is detailed in chapter 6.12.1 of the 3rd Intel's manual:

> When the processor performs a call to the exception- or interrupt-handler procedure:
>
> - **If** the handler procedure is going to be executed at a **numerically lower privilege level, a stack switch occurs**.
>   When the stack switch occurs:
>   -. The segment selector and stack pointer for the stack to be used by the handler are obtained from the TSS for the currently executing task. On this new stack, the processor pushes the stack segment selector and
>   stack pointer of the interrupted procedure.
>   [redacted]
> - **If** the handler procedure is going to be executed at the **same privilege level** as the interrupted procedure:
>   a. The processor saves the current state of the EFLAGS, CS, and EIP registers on the current stack (see Figure
>   6-4).
>   [redacted]

It's worth noting that in 64-bit mode the task switching mechanism is no longer supported.
We cannot `call` or `jmp` or use a task gate.
However, confusingly enough, the TSS is still used and mandatory. This structure is now used as it has been used in practice by the mainstream OSes: as a global (read: the same for every task, at least in theory) buffer where to store stack switching and other information.
Also worth noting is that in 64-bit mode the new IST mechanism is used for task switching (see section 6.14.5 of the 3rd Intel's manual).

---

> How can it work if I don’t have this TSS ? Is it because when interrupts occurs the CPU will still automatically push EIP, CS, EFLAGS, EPS, SS and restore them on iret ?

The CPU won't use the TSS when there is no privilege level change. To understand what is pushed and in what order, see this picture below taken from Intel's manual volume 3:

[image: Stack switching]

---

> If I load a single TSS, how this interrupt will know that it should use this TSS ? With ltr instruction that will take the according tss segment inside the GDT?

When an interrupt occurs and the CPU realizes that a privilege change is going to happen it will read the `tr` register to reach the current TSS.
Since loading the `tr` is a privilege operation, the OS is in control of what TSS will be used.
Infact, if the OS wanted to use two different TSS, *A* and *B*, for two different programs *Pa* and *Pb*, it will reload `tr` each time is about to execute one of those programs.

So yes, the `ltr` instruction is how the OS controls the TSS currently active.

---

> Not really related, but when using hardware context switching and jmp to one TSS, will it automatically jump to the previous (no next field so I’m a little bit lost) tss segment automatically when return ?

A task switching, when supported, can be invoked with: `jmp`, `call`, `int`, an interrupt, or an exception.
All of these methods but `jmp` will link the current task (the one being switched out) to the new task (the one being switched in).
This is achieved through the *Previous Task Link* field in the TSS, the new TSS will have this field set to the old TSS selector.
The new task is said to be *nested*.
The CPU will also use the *NT* (Nested Task) flag to keep track of whenever the current task is nested or not.

If a task is nested (i.e. invoked with `call`, `int`, and interrupt or an exception), using the `iret` instruction the CPU will read the *Previous Task Link* to find the suspended Task to resume.

Note that only `iret` can be used, even if the task switching was done with `call` (which normally pairs with `ret/retf`).

This is a picture from the Manual:

[image: Task linking]

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation! Things are much clearer now but I am still wondering if the RPL field is used when selecting a TSS segment to jmp to or call to ? Also the previous task field must be set « by hand » and it is not automatic ?

Comment: @Leosa99_ The RPL is surely used when calling/jumping to Task gate, but it doesn't seem to be used when using a Task descriptor directly. The RPL of the TSS selector inside a Task gate is not used. Intel's manuals have more details, I don't remember them all :) The Previous Task LInk is set automatically by the CPU when switching task (unless `jmp` is used) but the OS can overwrite/write it manually (along with setting the *NT* flag) to fake a nested task.